# Why does strtotime('2016-01-01') result to 1.1.2015?

Tags: php, strtotime

There's been a reported bug in my application where I was using the strtotime function on the mysql date returned from DB. It all worked well until today when a bug occured.

When I run:

```
date('j.n.o', strtotime('2016-01-01'))
```

I get result "1.1.2015" for some reason.

But if I run

```
date('j.n.o', strtotime('2016-02-01'))
```

I get "1.2.2016" which is correct but I have no idea why the first example failed.

I could easily do a workaround to make this work properly but I'm wondering in particular why does this function return such strange results with this input? I've checked with php 5.3 and 7.0 and I get same results

Comment: o  == ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0) source: [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Y` instead of `o` for the year

```
echo date('j.n.Y', strtotime('2016-01-01'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> o --- ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

vs

> Y --- A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

Comment: that did it. I was sure strtotime was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

PHP contains in-built date functions to format given date or time. These are,

date()
date_format()

This function accepts two optional arguments. i.e. format and timestamp. The code shows an example for the PHP date() function.

/ returns date for timestamp, in dd/mm/YYYY format
echo date("d-m-Y",time());